# How to clear task and start new activity from widget

Tags: android

I have an application with the following activities

```
MainActivity > DetailActivity
```

If I start the `DetailActivity` from the `MainActivity` using the following flags in my intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

The current task will be cleared and a new task will be started with only `DetailActivity` on the stack.

However, if I currently have `MainActivity` on the stack, and I start a new instance of `MainActivity` from the a widget using the same flags, I get two instances of `MainActivity` overlaying each-other.

Is it not possible to clear the task and start a new instance of `MainActivity` from the widget?

Comment: add code used to lounch activities thanks.